# android: how to add a new line

Tags: android, string, newline

I have a very simple question.. I am using the following code to edit the title of my option menu.

```
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
menu.findItem(R.id.default_email).setTitle("Default E-mail: "+gmailAc);
```

I just want to add a new line after "Default E-mail".. I have tried \n and \r\n but none of them worked.. Its quite strange that android doesn't support even the simplest of the formatting commands.. 
Can anyone guide me here.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line breaks are not possible in menu.

check this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083569/android-menu-line-break)

this is same as what you are trying to do.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember, strings in Android can be declared in HTML format. Why don't you try

```
<br />
```

Comment: can you tell me how to use it?