# displaying menu items in 2 lines

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

I have a relative layout and option menu with 5 items. the problem is that I cant see the
last item on my phone, as the screen too small. Is there any way to display the items in 2 lines?

this is my layout:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my menu:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/menu_settings"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_all"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/menu_all"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_North"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/menu_North"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_TelAviv"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/menu_TelAviv"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_Jerusalem"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/menu_Jerusalem"/>

    <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_South"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/menu_South"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: can you please screenshot here , that how it looks?

Comment: can't add a pic as my emulator has a prob at the moment.. I am working on my own phone

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6083878/1662629